# unknown provider, service isn't being injected

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-services

I'm confused about how to create services and inject (use) them in my controllers. It seems it is very simple but I can't get my code to work. I'm stuck with this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Flickr
```

I define the service:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
.provider('Flickr', function(){
    // service code
})
```

Include it in my app module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.services'
]);
```

and then reference it in a controller:

```
app.controller('FlickrCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Flickr', function($scope, $routeParams, Flickr){
    // controller stuff
});
```

and reference the files at the bottom of `index.html`

```
<script src='js/app.js'></script>
<script src='js/config.js'></script>
<script src='js/services/Flickr.js'></script>
<script src='js/controllers/flickr.js'></script>
```

Why can't angular find the service I defined when I ask it to inject it into the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.provider`, you are creating a provider that should return a configurable singleton. In many cases, this singleton is a singleton factory, spitting back an object that has services you can use.

First, you would need to refer to it as `FlickrProvider` instead of `Flickr` when you call it to set a config.

Without seeing more of your code, I can't tell if you're returning a `new Flickr` from your provider, which is what you would need to do in order to use a service instance in the way I think you're trying to do.

check out: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Basically though, in order to inject and use `Flickr` like you are trying to do, you would need to do something like this:

```
.provider('Flickr',function FlickrProvider(){
    this.$get = function(){
         return new Flickr()
    }


})

function Flickr(){

    this.doSomething: function(){
         //do something or return something
    }

}
```

If you only want to define a service, and not make it a configurable provider, then use `.factory` instead, which will only need `Flickr` to be injected in order to be used.

Comment: yeah I had to name it `FlickrProvider` in my config file. Thank you!